# expandable getElementsByTagName array

Tags: javascript, xml

Bet this is really simple, but I have been strugling for a couple of hours to get it work.

Im reading an XML file with javascript but I cant get it read al my noods, only when I change the index (manually ) in the array it read the second line.

This is the line I use to write out the line with

```
 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

As i said, when i change the ("name")[0] to ("name")[1] it read the second line.
Is there a way i maybe can create a loop ? of use .length ?

This is some of the code.

```
document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x =xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("products");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
```

And the XML file

```
<productlist>
<products>
  <title>Kök</title>
  <product><id>23</id><name>Bestick</name><price>45</price></product>
  <product><id>47</id><name>Tallrikar</name><price>99</price></product>
  <product><id>54</id><name>Glas</name><price>64</price></product>
  <product><id>68</id><name>Koppar</name><price>125</price></product>
</products>
<products>
  <title>Sängkläder</title>
  <product><id>12</id><name>Lakan</name><price>89</price></product>
  <product><id>43</id><name>Kudde</name><price>148</price></product>
  <product><id>48</id><name>Täcke</name><price>345</price></product>
</products>
</productlist>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have one loop, apparently you need another one:

```
document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("products");
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  // Get all names on current products node, and loop
  var names = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name");
  for(var j=0; j<names.length; j++) {
    document.write(names[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I been trying to get it work with the loop but couldn't get it right.
Thank you again.